# Add languages to GeSHi plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I'm using GeSHi plugin for writing code in my Joomla site.

It works, but there's some language that are not supported (powershell, SQL) that I need.

In the [GeSHi homepage](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) I've seen that they've released a version in which these languages are supported, so I'd like to use it in my site.

Is there a way to import it in my Joomla installation?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution by myself.

In the Joomla folder go to `administrator/components/com_scriptcodehighlighter/models/forms` and open the file `scriptcodehighlighter.xml`. There's the list of all supported formats.

Then add following options:

```
<option value="sql">SQL</option>
<option value="powershell">POWERSHELL</option>
```

Just for be sure, I've followed the alphabetical order of the file, so I've put them in right positions (but I don't know if it's has any importance).

Do the same thing for the file `/components/com_scriptcodehighlighter/models/forms/scriptcodehighlighter.xml`.

Now when I add the code in the dropdown list I can see missing languages, and they also work correctly in article.

Comment: The Geshi plugin was removed from Joomla! standard distribution per 3.1 release it is no longer available by default. What extension do you use?

Comment: I've used [Script Code Highlighter](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/script-code-highlighter)